# Atom: add default project folder on start with no tabs

Tags: atom-editor

I have one single project folder that I work on every time. I would like that when I start Atom that the project folder is shown and no tabs are open.

I am using Ubutnu 14.04 LTS and Atom 1.5.3.

At the moment, every time I close and reopen Atom, the last session is shown. This is good, because my project folder is always loaded correctly. Unfortunately, all tabs are also open from my previous session.

I have checked under **Core Settings** ->  *Open Emty Editor On Start* (Automatically open an empty editor on startup). But still, the editor is not empty on startup. Am I missing anything? How can I get this problem solved?